# How Google Keep app only show element if screen reader is used?

Tags: ios, accessibility

As title says, how does Google Keep app show different element depending on whether a screen reader is used? I always thought it wasn't possible to know if someone was using a screen reader.

In the Google Keeps app on iPhone:

- Select a note > choose menu > delete
- Note is deleted and page with all notes is reshown.
- A small message "note was trashed" appears.

  - If NOT using VoiceOver, message does *not* have a button and it disappears on its own.
  - If using VoiceOver, focus goes to the message and there's an OK button. Message does not disappear without user action.

I know that I can make a screen reader see and announce elements that are visibly hidden. And that I can set visible elements to be hidden from a screen reader. But this is different: the button is only there and visible (and must be pressed) when the screen reader is used.

(As part 2 to question, I'd also like to know if this is possible using HTML.)

Comment: What does a good answer look like here? Do you want source code for Keep in iOS, (probably) Java and HTML? When I tried this on a Samsung S21 Ultra and a Google Pixel 7 pro, I did not see a difference in the Undo buttons presence or the Toast message's duration or structure

Comment: I removed the bit about Android; thought I had seen it like I did on the iPhone. (Just retested on iPhone and took screenshots both ways.) A good answer would be a suggestion for how Google might be doing it. For all I know, there's a new IOS setting that tells you. Everything I've read says it's bad to detect screen readers, but here is Google doing it and providing extra functionality. Interesting, I thought.